# Fullcalendar unable to locate /data feed

Tags: javascript, python, apache, flask, fullcalendar

I am trying to use Fullcalendar to render events returned from another application written in Python using Flask. I have managed to query the application and return JSON to Fullcalendar on my test setup (local to my laptop) which works fine.

When I tried to deploy the same code to the server (CentOS 7 with Apache), Apache logs the following error:

```
AH00128: File does not exist: /etc/httpd/htdocs/data
```

An extract from the calendar.html template is as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,listWeek'
            },
            defaultView: 'listWeek',
            editable: false,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: {
                url: 'data',
                error: function() {
                    $('#script-warning').show();
                }
            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have identified that the `url: 'data'` line appears to be controlling the path, but I have been unable to set anything there that works. I cannot see anywhere else in the code where I can set a path - clearly `/etc/httpd/htdocs/data/` is invalid - how can I configure the path so that the data is rendered?

EDIT: I believe this is an Apache problem - my conf file is as follows:

```
<virtualhost *:443>
  ServerName server.example.com
  LogLevel info
  SSLEngine On
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3

  WSGIDaemonProcess fs_calendar user=apache group=apache threads=5 home=/var/www/fs_calendar/
  WSGIScriptAlias /fs_calendar /var/www/fs_calendar/calendar.wsgi

  <directory /var/www/fs_calendar>
    WSGIProcessGroup fs_api
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </directory>

  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.example.com/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.example.com/privkey.pem
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.example.com/chain.pem
</virtualhost>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like an error fullCalendar (or the browser / JS engine in general) would log. It won't know the structure of the files on your disk. Where did you actually see that error? Anyway you need to point your URL at wherever the endpoint is installed on your server which serves the event data. We don't know where (or even whether) you deployed that.

Comment: Sorry yes I should have provided more info. That error was logged by Apache in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: Ok so there's no file at that location, which is the location on disk pointed at by the URL which the browser generated (I imagine it will have been `http://yourwebsitehost/data`, you can verify it by watching the request in your browser, and/or checking other apache logs). Did you actually deploy your server-side script, and if so, did you put it in the right place?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems the way Flask runs the code the paths are obscured, but the files are in the correct locations as far as I can tell. I will have to dig into the Apache config some more as this seems to be where the issue lies

Comment: I just wanted to update here as I can't find a solution to this anywhere. Further testing reveals that the server IS serving the data, if I browse to `https://myhost/data` I see the JSON output, however it seems Fullcalendar does not. Am at a loss as to what to change next. Any help very much welcomed.

Comment: can you try `url: "/data"`. just in case. Or even `url: "https://myhost/data"` to be absolutely certain it's pointing to the same place.

Comment: Success! Thanks so much, this was the key. I added the full URL into `calendar.html` and the error disappeared. If you add this an an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there's a mismatch about where your URL is pointing to.

Try putting

```
url: "https://myhost/data"
```

in your code to be absolutely certain it's pointing to the right place.